# Transparent font with stroke

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this kind of behaviour with a text in pure css:

[image]

I've managed to quite get there using `text-stroke` but I'm not satisfied - at all - with the result:

```
font-size: 200px;
text-transform: uppercase;
stroke-width: 2px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--white);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
color: transparent;
```

There a live example [here](https://codepen.io/TheBrickSlayer/pen/zYMzMja)
as you can see the effect isn't quite the same. I was wondering if it's possibile to achive it in pure css, or if I need to create a custom font for that.
Also, since `text-stroke` is only available for `Webkit`, is there an alternative ?

```css
.test {
  font-size: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>    
  </head>
  <style>
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
<div class="test">
  Ciao!
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Link is broken: `https://%28https//codepen.io/TheBrickSlayer/pen/zYMzMja)%5Bhere%5D` post the code as a [mcve], please.

Comment: This seems like something you could perfectly show us inside a snippet instead of a broken external link (this is why there s a policy against external links: this one was born broken). Please convert into a snippet so we can see what you see and help you further. Also, `text-stroke` is pretty widely supported at this time, with some caveats: https://caniuse.com/?search=text-stroke - not just in webkit.

Comment: Link updated. Added a code snippet.  _looks similar enough for me_  : the effect is very different. The text in the snippet is very _sharpy_ besides the font family being the same.

Comment: is the font used in the image poppins?

Comment: Yes, the font used in the image and in the snippet is Poppins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the font is the same then you should be able to achieve the same effect. I think you're just missing the `font-weight` declaration. Updated example:

```css
.test {
  font-size: 200px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
    color: transparent;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;900&display=swap' rel='stylesheet'>    
  </head>
  <style>
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins';font-size: 22px;
}
</style>
<div class="test">
  Ciao!
</div>
</html>
```